# Page scrolls top automatically in 2.0rc1

Tags: rally

[image]I have multiple pie charts and grids in the page, so page has to be scrolled to view the charts.

Problem :
When pagination in the grid, or slice in the chart is clicked, page automatically scrolls top because of which user has to scroll down every time to view the chart/grid.

i am using "App SDK 2.0 RC1"

Any fix for this ?

Sample code :

```
items : [
                    {
                        xtype  : 'container',
                        id     : 'releaseBox',
                        layout : 'vbox'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype  : 'container',
                        id     : 'chart1',
                        layout : 'vbox'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype  : 'container',
                        id     : 'chart2',
                        layout : 'vbox'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype  : 'container',
                        id     : 'chart3',
                        layout : 'vbox'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype  : 'container',
                        id     : 'chart4',
                        layout : 'vbox'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype  : 'container',
                        id     : 'chart5',
                        layout : 'vbox'
                    }

                ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a listener for that event and adding this code to scroll to the desired id:

```
location.hash = '#chart' + chartNumber;
```

Comment: the problem is, when user clicks on the slice of the pie chart, page automatically scrolls to the top. I need to prevent it from scrolling to the top of the page when user clicks on the slice of the pie chart. Even page scrolls to top when user clicks on the pagination of the grid. How can i stop the page from scrolling to the top ?

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your project? It might help explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: attached screenshot please provide your suggestion/fix

Comment: do we have any fix for this ?